# Accessing variables in a JSON?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently working with the Bing Isochrone Api.  I set up my http request in Angular using the HTTPClient.  This is the example of the data set I get back:

```
{
"authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
"brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
"copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
"resourceSets": [{
    "estimatedTotal": 1,
    "resources": [{
        "__type": "IsochroneResponse:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
        "origin": {
            "latitude": 47.640068,
            "longitude": -122.129858
        },
        "polygons": [{
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [48.22848, -122.12867],
                    [48.22613, -122.10625],
                    [48.229309, -122.08228],
                    [48.23733, -122.07666],
                    [48.24474, -122.05325],
                    [48.24469, -122.0532],
                    [48.24424, -122.05386],
                    [48.23119, -122.06654],         
                    [48.22848, -122.12867]
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }]
}],
"statusCode": 200,
"statusDescription": "OK",
"traceId": "4ed97517798141a1b5bb9df40509f190|CO30305304|7.7.0.0|"
```

}

I can get to the resourceSets with this

```
 this
        .http
        .get(`http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/Isochrones?waypoint=\
        ${this.testPointlat},${this.testPointlong}&maxTime=15&timeUnit=Minutes\
        &dateTime=2017-11-27T18:00:00-08:00&travelMode=Driving\
        &key=$$$$$$$$$$$$$
        `).subscribe(
          (response) => {
            this.driveTimeCoords = response.resourceSets;
            console.log(this.driveTimeCoords);
            const polygons = this.driveTimeCoords.resources.polygons;
            console.log(polygons);
          }
        );
      })
```

So this.driveTimeCoords gives me an array... My attempt after it doesn't work obviously as it says undefined.  Would i do a .foreach with an if or something?  I'm probably overthinking this. All I want are the coordinates so I can then .map() them into a geojson featuregroup for leaflet.

Thanks!

Edit:
On console.log this.driveTimeCoords I get

```
[{…}]0: estimatedTotal: 1resources: [{…}]
```

Comment: `console.log(this.driveTimeCoords);` gives you an output? Would you mind posting it

Comment: It gives me an [{}] with estimated total and resources in it

Comment: It is an array so you need to reference the index in the array. So you loop over it or directly reference the index.

Comment: Are you just wanting to add like lat/lng keys to that array of coords in resourcesets.resources.polygons so you can map an ILatLng model easier or something? Not sure I understand what you want based on what you're saying and what I'm seeing.

Comment: Chris W I just want to remove that array of coordinates and assign it to another variable.

Comment: Maybe Angular doesn't know the type of `response`, so `resourceSets` is not a property of `response`. You can either go for typing your `http.get` like this `http.get<MyClass>` or you can bypass this with : `this.driveTimeCoords = response['resourceSets']` to force the access of this attribute.

Comment: @epascarello I am going to try that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON formatting is off: note how `resourceSets`, `resources` and `polygons` are object arrays, meaning you need to call the array's index to access the data, like so:

```
this.driveTimeCoords = response.resourceSets[0];
console.log(this.driveTimeCoords);
const polygons = this.driveTimeCoords.resources[0].polygons[0];
console.log(polygons);
```

To fix this issue, your JSON should be formatted like this:

```
{
"authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
"brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
"copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
"resourceSets": {
    "estimatedTotal": 1,
    "resources": {
        "__type": "IsochroneResponse:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
        "origin": {
            "latitude": 47.640068,
            "longitude": -122.129858
        },
        "polygons": {
            "coordinates": [
                {"latitude": 48.22848, "longitude": -122.12867},
                {"latitude": 48.22613, "longitude": -122.10625},
                {"latitude": 48.229309, "longitude": -122.08228},
                {"latitude": 48.23733, "longitude": -122.07666},
                {"latitude": 48.24474, "longitude": -122.05325},
                {"latitude": 48.24469, "longitude": -122.0532},
                {"latitude": 48.24424, "longitude": -122.05386},
                {"latitude": 48.23119, "longitude": -122.06654},         
                {"latitude": 48.22848, "longitude": -122.12867}
            ]
         }
    }
},
"statusCode": 200,
"statusDescription": "OK",
"traceId": "4ed97517798141a1b5bb9df40509f190|CO30305304|7.7.0.0|"
}
```

I added variable names to the coordinates, for easier comprehension of the data being read.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your JSON object, it looks like `this.driveTimeCoords` which is a reference to the `resourceSets` in your JSON, is an array, which, for every property you seem to want (resource, polygons, coordinates) all successively are arrays as well. Thus, you must do a sequence of nested `.map()` operations.

Try the following:

```
var result = this.driveTimeCoords.map((obj)=>{
    return obj.resources.map((resource)=>{
       return resource.polygon.map((poly)=> poly.coordinates )
    })
})
```

Doing this, makes it so that, if any of those arrays contain multiple references, you'd get them all. Afterwards, you could flatten the array, or simply reference the first one as another guy suggested `result[0][0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as they are arrays, you need to access via thier index:

```js
let json = {
"authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
"brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
"copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
"resourceSets": [{
    "estimatedTotal": 1,
    "resources": [{
        "__type": "IsochroneResponse:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
        "origin": {
            "latitude": 47.640068,
            "longitude": -122.129858
        },
        "polygons": [{
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [48.22848, -122.12867],
                    [48.22613, -122.10625],
                    [48.229309, -122.08228],
                    [48.23733, -122.07666],
                    [48.24474, -122.05325],
                    [48.24469, -122.0532],
                    [48.24424, -122.05386],
                    [48.23119, -122.06654],         
                    [48.22848, -122.12867]
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }]
}],
"statusCode": 200,
"statusDescription": "OK",
"traceId": "4ed97517798141a1b5bb9df40509f190|CO30305304|7.7.0.0|"
}

let polys = json['resourceSets'][0].resources[0].polygons;

let o = document.getElementById('output');
o.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(polys);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this formating you can acces coordinate with these paths :

```
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][0][0] = 48.22848
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][0][1] = -122.12867
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][1][0] = 48.22613
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][1][1] = -122.10625
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][2][0] = 48.229309
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][2][1] = -122.08228
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][3][0] = 48.23733
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][3][1] = -122.07666
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][4][0] = 48.24474
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][4][1] = -122.05325
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][5][0] = 48.24469
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][5][1] = -122.0532
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][6][0] = 48.24424
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][6][1] = -122.05386
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][7][0] = 48.23119
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][7][1] = -122.06654
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][8][0] = 48.22848
.resourceSets[0].resources[0].polygons[0].coordinates[0][8][1] = -122.12867
```